# TCP socket and binary data

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, binary-data

How to send binary data (01110110 for exemple) with C# throught a TCP (using SSL) socket ?

I'm using :

```
SslStream.Write()
```

and

```
h[0] = (byte)Convert.ToByte("01110110");
```

isn't working

Comment: Please attend a programming course or, you know, research a bit or something. I'm not sure where i'd begin. http://www.doingitwrong.com/

Comment: I never thought I'd see this in real life: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Boolean-Integers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a little clearer about what `01110110` is. Is it decimal? Hex? Binary? Note that "binary data" can be represented in any base.

Since it's 8 digits of 0 and 1, and since you used the word "binary" in your question, I'm going to guess that it's binary, which is `118` decimal (google for `0b0111010 in decimal`).

So you can just do

`h[0] = 118;`

My feeling is that you'll need to learn a bit more about the basics of how bytes work and the binary system before you'll be able to make much further progress. A good beginning programming book should help.